# Asymptotic estimate on minimum of a function

Tags: asymptotics, almost-periodic-functions

Let 
$$V(x) = 2 - \sin(2\pi x) - \sin(2\pi\sqrt{2} x)$$
for $x\in \mathbb{R}$. For each $r>0$, let 
$$a_r = \min\{a>0: V(a)=r\}$$
We can see that
$$ r = V(a_r) = \min\{V(x): x\in [0,a_r]\}$$
I want to estimate (if any) grownth rate of
$$ a_r \leq Cr^{-\theta}.$$
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You would probably gain quite a lot from doing this numerically in terms of intuition. That is, calculate $a_r$ for a range of different $r$ (i.e. discretise $[0,4]$) via optimisation and plot it next to a few curves of the form $Cr^{-\theta}$. $C$ can be calculated by viewing $a_1$. 

When finding $a_r$ it has to be the minimum. If our objective is $(r-2+\sin(2\pi x)+\sin(2\pi \sqrt{2}x)^2$ then this is differentiable. We can do a deterministic optimisation method such as gradient descent or Newton Raphson (or LBFGS etc). A starting point of zero is likely to give us the smallest solution.

Comment: Can you show me how to code that?